# Is registering a client app in Soundcloud still available in any way?

Tags: client, registration, soundcloud

I am trying to register my app through SoundCloud for developers and got redirected to this google form.[image: google form I receive]

I still need to work with SoundCloud in my app. What should I do?

Comment: I have the same problem. I asked both the general Soundcloud Twitter account as well as their developer Twitter account, but no answer :/